# Delete selected row - not last saved row

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, row

App like a calender

I want to delete specific rows in my tableView. Each row is saved by a datepicker. The Title und Subtitle is perfekt. It shows the Name and the time selected in datePicker.

If I create more than one event, my tableView shows it in the correct order.

- Event Nr.1 - 11:00 h
- Event 2 - 11:10 h
- so on

Also if I create the event in mixed intervals at first 11:10h than 11:00h
But If I want to delete the Event Nr.1 it deletet Event Nr.2

It seems that my code deleted always the last saved event.
Edit mode:

```
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notifcation];
        [notificationsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

        [tableview reloadData];
    }



}
```

Tableview:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...


self.notificationsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]];
notifcation = [self.notificationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
//UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Was in der Zelle als Titel steht
//[[cell textLabel] setText:[notifcation alertBody]];
[[cell textLabel] setText:@"Event"];
//[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description]];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:notifcation.fireDate]];
[dateFormatter release];
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Add some lines in your method**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
                                            forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   if(tableView.editing && editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
            [tableView beginUpdates];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notifcation];
                [notificationsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            // Animate the deletion from the table.
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            [tableView endUpdates];
            [tableView reloadData];
     }

}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable. 
    // UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    return YES;
  }
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me. I create 4 events in this order: 3:00h, 3:10h, 2:15h, 2:30h - the order in my table is rigth with: 2:15h, 2:30h, 3:00h, 3:10h. So if I now klick my edit button and want to delete the event 3:00h the result is, that 3:10 was deleted. Now I deleted 2:30h, and 3:00h is deleted. Whats wrong???

Comment: Try to add 1 in indexpath.row.